# Mapbox Feature ID parameter missing

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I took this demo from mapbox:

```
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/
```

I put in my own GeoJson file in replacement of the demo one, the code is here:

```
https://codepen.io/hiven/pen/rNYdvdg?editors=1112
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: The feature id parameter must be provided.
```

I can't understand what this is saying, as a feature ID is provided here in this snippet:

```
   map.addLayer({
        'id': 'state-borders',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'states',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#627BC1',
            'line-width': 2
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to add `generateId: true` to your `addSource` method params.

```js
map.addSource('states', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': 'https://hiven.github.io/map2/hexagons.geojson',                         
            'generateId': true //This ensures that all features have unique IDs           
        });
```